# External jQuery file loop skips over first or last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, each

I'm loading information to my page from an external javascript file. This file finds divs on the page with a certain class name, then populates the div's content based on a custom attribute, which is a link to an api. The function in the external file loops through each div with the class and dynamically populates the div's id.

here is the code for the divs on my page:

```
<div class="classname" data-apisrc="www.someapi1.com" id="box1"></div>
<div class="classname" data-apisrc="www.someapi2.com" id="box2"></div>
<div class="classname" data-apisrc="www.someapi3.com" id="box3"></div>
```

here is the code in the external file:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.classname").load("https://...somewebsite.com.html div.box-container");

    var i=0;

    var box = $("div.classname");

    $(box).each(function(apisrc, div_id) {
        i++;

        var apisrc = $(this).attr("data-apisrc");
        var div_id = 'box'+i;
        $(this).attr('id',div_id);
        $(this).val(i);

        $this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: apisrc,
            async: true,
            success: function(result) {
                ...loads content into each div
            },
            error: function() {
                $this.text("content could not be loaded");
                //alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is the only function in the external file. it is being called in the current file at the top of the page, but that shouldnt matter because the function is wrapped in a document.ready function

There are three of these divs on the page. For some reason, it only shows content from the second and third div and skips the first until i reload the page several times.

I don't see anything wrong with my function. any advice?

Comment: Are you using `i` inside of the `...loads content into each div` part of your code?

Comment: Why are you overriding the arguments (`apisrc`, `div_id`)?

Comment: you are doing `$("div.classname").load(...` as well as a ajax call to load data inside each div?? if you are doing some delta changes on top of that from the `ajax` then do it once the `load(...` is completed.

Comment: @aquinas no, I'm not using i inside the ajax success function. i am using the "div_id" variable inside of the ajax function to target and fill content specific to each div

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee the .load() function finds the div on my current page with a certain class name and loads an empty container into that div. 

then the .each function populates the content into that container dynamically. or at least that's what i want to happen.

how do i make sure it runs after the load function?

Comment: @Teemu how am i overrideing the apisrc and div_id? I guess i shouldve left out the ids in my first code block. technically they are empty to start, then the function adds the id for each div

Comment: you are executing `load` already on `$("div.classname")` right? so after finding that you are trying to load. check my answer how to do it after load is completed.

Comment: ?? `var apisrc = ...`, `var div_id = ...` override the arguments passed to `each`. `apisrc` contains the index of the element in the jQuery object, `div_id` contains the element itself, you wouldn't need `i` at all, if you used the arguments ...

Comment: @Teemu yeah she is overriding the current item reference, and then using `this` to refer the current item. no need of that overriding!!

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr` :-)

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee i changed it to that right before I read your answer! it worked thanks! still new to nesting jquery and ajax calls.

Comment: @HollyMichelle you are welcome, miles to go, try hard learning, good luck :)

Comment: @OscarJara good catch, thanks!

Comment: @HollyMichelle Oops, I forgot! `prop` is valid but since you are dealing with `data` attributes then you can use `$(this).data('apisrc')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 
`$("div.classname").load("https://...somewebsite.com.html div.box-container");`
this is overriding your content in the first (or any arbitrary) `div`

and some times (few of the many you tried) the `load` resolves first, and then the `ajax` so the changes inside `ajax success` are affecting in the DOM. If you need both the contents (from `load(...)`) and you are adding inside `ajax success` on top of that, then do it once the load is completed, pass a callback as second argument of load, and move the entire code there.

eg:

```
$("div.classname").load("https://...somewebsite.com.html div.box-container", function(){
    //place the code you want to execute after load is completed
});
```